# Python - list not populated while thread is alive

Tags: python, multithreading

I created two simple functions to see how threads are working. I want to populate a list while a thread is alive. But the list returned is empty.

```
def test_function():
    x=1
    while x<=100000:
        x=x+1


def thread_function(funct):
    t = threading.Thread(target=funct)
    t.start()
    l = []
    while t.isAlive():
        l.append(datetime.datetime.now())
    return l

print(thread_function(test_function())) #returns []
```

Comment: What if the thread runs _and finishes_ immediately, before you enter the `t.isAlive()` loop? You have no way to see if this happened or to inspect the loop produced inside the thread.

Comment: By the way, don't call your list `list`. That is the name of the type.

Comment: [kelwood](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3890632/khelwood) Thank you for the observation. I edited my code.

Comment: [Useless](http://stackoverflow.com/users/212858/useless) you are right, I found out that test_function runs too quickly. I edited the code in order to run longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're executing `test_function` in the main thread, and pass `None` to your `thread_function` instead of the function itself.

```
print(thread_function(test_function()))
```

should be

```
print(thread_function(test_function))
```

Comment: I marked this answer as accepted. [omri_saadon](http://stackoverflow.com/users/3417069/omri-saadon) has the same solution but [Jean-François Fabre](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6451573/jean-fran%c3%a7ois-fabre) answered first. Thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the function `test_function` instead of the returned value of this function `test_function()`, which is None.

So, basically the function that you give as a target to the thread is None.

Change this :

```
print(thread_function(test_function()))
```

To:

```
print(thread_function(test_function))
```